# HTML Email Signatures

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to make an HTML email signature.

I have managed to get it the way I would like it to look, but something strange seems to be happening when viewing the signature in the Outlook client compared to Outlook on the web, please see image below.

This is what it looks like when viewed on the web.
[image: Outlook On The Web]

And this is what it looks like when viewed in the Outlook client.

[image]

Here is my HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5755c2b9356fb0c7e2943cf6/t/58800e158419c2ec7abbbd80/1484787227067/TheTest_banner_r2.png?format=2500w" width="571" height="168">

  <div class="links" style="font-size: 15px;">
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a><p> | </p>
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a><p> | </p>
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a><p> | </p>
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a><p> | </p>
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a><p> | </p>
    <a href="#"><p>Test</p></a>
  </div>

  <p style="font-size: 11px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br/>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
p {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}
a {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}
.links p {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
  display: inline;
}
```

https://codepen.io/atomicaltv/pen/rogxMO

Comment: Some email clients strip the head and styles tags out of the html. It's recommended to only use inline css for any styling inside an email to not get this issue. See this tool from mailchimp to inline everything: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

And heres is their reference for css support inside mails: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: @AgashThamo. Thank you. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. According to the second link you supplied my code should be fine for Outlook client however it does not specify if it will work with the latest Outlook client.

Comment: Did you try to inline the css? because to me, it looks like Outlook is not getting any css definition at all (since the *p* tags act as a normal paragraph instead of being inline as you define in your css). What was the html like after inlining?

Comment: https://codepen.io/atomicaltv/pen/qLGadq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it seems Outlook doesn't like the *display* property being changed.
I switched your code a bit, so it uses *span* elements instead of *p*aragraphs, so they naturally align the way you want them to, without using the display property.

Here's the original (without inlined css):

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}

.links {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}

.links .link-text {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5755c2b9356fb0c7e2943cf6/t/58800e158419c2ec7abbbd80/1484787227067/TheTest_banner_r2.png?format=2500w" width="571" height="168">

  <div class="links" style="font-size: 15px;">
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text">Test</span></a>
  </div>

  <p style="font-size: 11px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br/>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's a inlined version, which I tested using Office365 Outlook client:

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}

.links {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}

.links .link-text {
  color: rgb(22, 31, 53);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="font-family: Georgia;color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5755c2b9356fb0c7e2943cf6/t/58800e158419c2ec7abbbd80/1484787227067/TheTest_banner_r2.png?format=2500w" width="571" height="168">

  <div class="links" style="font-size: 15px;color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a><span> | </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="link-text" style="color: rgb(22, 31, 53);">Test</span></a>
  </div>

  <p style="font-size: 11px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>

</body>

</html>
```

*Note: your CSS to change the color is redundant. I left it as is using the new elements, in case you wanted to change them later to actually meaningful things.*

Comment: Something I have just noticed is that the text and image don't align any more any ideas?

Comment: Can I get more infos, do you have a screenshot or anything the like? In my tests they do align.

Comment: I believe there is an issue where Outlook scales the image for some strange reason. On Office online or OWA it works perfectly everything algins etc, however, when you view it on the Outlook client the image scales rather too big or too small.

Comment: Well you did define the width and height of the image. I'd go the other route and make it a bit more flexible. If you could show me what exactly happens I could help ya out again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.links{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Still getting the exact same issue trying it this. I also tried using https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/ with this still no luck. Thanks for the help.